# Permissions for a new user / Parse-server-Heroku

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, heroku, parse-server

I just created a new user on parse-server/Heroku. Using code like this:

```
PFUser *x = [[PFUser alloc] init];
x.username = @"XXX";
x.password = @"yyyy";
x.email = @"email123@abc.com";
[x signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"kensu registration ALL OK!!!!");
    } else if (error) {
        NSLog(@"kensu registration error: %@",error);
    }
}];
```

The user creation went fine. And I can log in witn this new user.

The problem comes after.

When I log in with the new user, I am not allowed to make any update on my mongoDB.

I get this kind of error message:

```
[Error]: Permission denied for action update on class ....
```

If I log with the unique user I had before, I can update without any problem. **Why?**

I looked at the user collection to see any difference, then tried a few things, but without success.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you implemented any ACLs or CLPs?

Comment: No. At least as far as I am aware of. But I solved my problem in the meanwhile, by looking at the _SCHEMA Collection on mLab.